# Number of possible marriage arrangements if Marriage Condition is satisfied

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Suppose I have a set of $n$ boys and each subset of $1\leqslant k \leqslant n$ boys knows at least $k$ girls then this means that the set of boys $B$ satisfies the marriage condition. 
I am doing an exercise from a Graph Theory book and it says we can show by induction on $n$ that the number of possible marriage arrangements is $\geqslant t!$ if every individual boy knows at least $t \leqslant n$ girls or there are $\geqslant t!/(t-n)!$ possible marriages if each individual boy knows at least $t>n$ girls.

I am struggling to see how the induction hypothesis can be implemented to prove the $n+1$ case. When you swap from the $n$ to $n+1$ case the conditions change and I can't see the link between them.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry I mave have confused you with the k's. I edited it. $t$ is a set natural number that each individual boy knows. I am working by induction on the size of the set of boys $n$. I want to show that the possible number of arrangements if $t>n$ and if $t\leqslant n$

Comment: The book says to prove by induction on $n$. It is Robin J Wilson, Introduction to Graph Theory, exercise 25.7 on pg115.

Comment: You didn't say that in your question.  I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Have you any other ideas @saulspatz ? I’ve tried doing it with induction on $m$ and induction on $t$ and can’t make progress.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this.  I'll look at it again in a little while.

Comment: Thank you. I’m very stressed about it

Comment: Look at "First proof of the marriage theorem" on page $3$ of https://www.math.tamu.edu/~catherine.yan/Files/C2A.pdf and then the proof of Marshall Hall's theorem on the next page.

Comment: Thank you for finding that. I have a couple of questions though if you don’t mind explaining. In the proof it doesn’t explain what $m$ is so why can we know $a$ is related to $m$ things in $X$.  Also I don’t why you can delete $x_i$ from $X$ and have Halls condition still apply in $S\{a}$. What if $S\{a}$ is related to $|S\{a}|$ things in $X$. Then deleting $x_i$ could potentially break Halls condition if $x_i$ is one of the things $S\{a}$ is related to in $X$?

Comment: $m$ is the number of things related to $a$.  It says, "let $R(a)=\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$.  Don't understand your other question.  $a$ is one of the boys.  How can deleting $a$ break Hall's condition?

Comment: Because it says to also delete $x_i$. Could doing this not break Halls condition if $x_i$ was one of the vertices that $S\{a}$ was connected to? As in $S\{a}$ satisfied Halls before with $x_i$ but not if this vertex is deleted

Comment: This is in case 1, right?  Here is says that for every proper subset $A\subset S$ we have $|R(A)|>|A|.  So, even if we delete one of the girls, Hall's condition holds.  You make a valid point, but it's dealt with in case 2.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I hadn’t reached case 2 yet as I was trying to understand case 1 first.

Comment: One more thing. Why in my question from the book I was reading say $\geqslant t!$ matchings if every boy knows at least $t$ girl’s AND $t\leqslant n$. Where does this condition $t\leqslant n$ come into play in the proof?

Comment: I think he's assuming that there are the same number of girls as boys.  Once you understand the proof, you should be able to modify it to take care of the case where there are more girls.  You need to do this to deal with $t>n.$

Comment: Ok. I will try to do that using the same ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry one final question. Why does it say induction on S and k. Isn’t it just doing induction on k?

Comment: Personally, I'd call it induction on $|S|$.  I don't see any induction on $k$.

Comment: I think it is doing this: show P (|S|=1,k=1) is true, Assume P (n,k) true for all $1\leqslant k \leqslant n $ is true. Inductive step is showing $P (n+1,k)$ true for all $1\leqslant k \leqslant n+1$. Do you think right?